# Firebase Storage Admin - Bucket not specified-

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-admin

I've got an onDelete trigger function to delete all files within a folder, and I am following it as per this post from GDE: https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/automatically-delete-your-firebase-storage-files-from-firestore-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase-36542c39ba0d

I initialise my app

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
```

And then have my onDelete function

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {deleteFiles} = require('../helpers/storageService');

module.exports = functions.firestore.document("designs/{userId}/designs/{designId}").onDelete((snap, context) => {
    console.log("triggered");
    context.params;
    return deleteFiles(context.params)
});
```

This all works fine, however its within the deleteFiles function that it fails

```
exports.deleteFiles = async function(params) {
    return admin.storage().bucket().deleteFiles({
        prefix: `designs/${params.userId}/designs/${params.designId}"`
    })
};
```

When this part of the function runs, it fails with `Bucket name not specified or invalid. Specify a valid bucket name via the storageBucket option when initializing the app`.

Does anyone know what is happening here? As far as i'm aware, I don't need to provide credentials to the Admin SDK when initialising because the triggers already have sufficient credentials.

Comment: Do you `initializeApp()` before importing `firebase-functions`?

Comment: Could debug to see the value of the bucket, before you call the delete function? also take a look at what @HiranyaJayathilaka mentioned